# Why is this expansion true?

Tags: summation

Why are this two sums equal?

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n i2^i = \sum_{j=1}^i\sum_{i=j}^n 2^i$$

I'm supposed to prove that both sums are the same.

Comment: Please check your indices i,j,k.

Comment: Now it makes sense!

Comment: Now what's that $k$ on the right side?  Please tell us when you have the final and correct version of your question.

Comment: you now have $i$ in 3 places on the RHS - you sure this is correct? How can outer sum be up to $i$ if the inner sums over $i$ as an index?

Comment: I would swap the two sums on the r.h.s.

Comment: Final version... Sorry for the mistakes

Comment: @ArieWortsman: At least one index is still wrong.

Comment: @Nikolaj-K If that was the case, then the problem would be wrong (This is how it appears)

Comment: OK then, the problem is wrong.  You shouldn't have $i$ as an endpoint in the outer sum on the right and also as the index variable for the inner sum.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
$$
\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{i=j}^n 2^k
= \sum_{j=1}^k 2^k \left(\sum_{i=j}^n 1 \right)
$$

Comment: How can $2^n$ ever  be obtained on the r.h.s.?

Comment: @Bernard the OP changed the question a couple times over :)

Answer (score 1):

On the left

$\sum_{i=1}^n i\,x^i = x\dfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}\sum_{i=1}^n x^i$

and on the right

$\sum_{i=j}^n x^i = \sum_{i=1}^n x^i - \sum_{i=1}^{j-1} x^i$

and using these re-writes you may reduce all expressions reduce via

$\sum_{k=1}^m x^k = x\,\dfrac{1-x^m}{1-x}$

Of course you may then substitute $x=2$, if you want.

---

You may check it on worlframalpha or so via

`Sum[i*x^i, {i, 1, n}] - Sum[Sum[x^i, {i, j, n}], {j, 1, n}] // Simplify`

I did that [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bi*x%5Ei,+%7Bi,+1,+n%7D%5D+-+Sum%5BSum%5Bx%5Ei,+%7Bi,+j,+n%7D%5D,+%7Bj,+1,+n%7D%5D).

---

It's not like the inner sum on the right hand side equals $i\,2^i$ so that there would be a straight forward reduction. Nevertheless, it's almost a given that there is a double counting argument and some sum that just reduces to $i\,2^i$ that "should" be written on the left hand side.

Answer (score 0):

The r.h.s. should be 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i 2^i,$$
and the equality is obvious.

Comment: The equality with $\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=j}^n 2^i$ (only in one spot different than what OP has written right now) is also true and less obvious.

Comment: Yes. One can sketch a triangle  filled with $2^k$s for various $k$s.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n i 2^i
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i 2^i\\
&=\sum_{1\le j\le i\le n} 2^i\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\color{red}{n}\sum_{i=j}^n 2^i 
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Without words**:

$$1\cdot2^1+2\cdot2^2+3\cdot2^3+4\cdot2^4+\cdots\\=\\
2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+\cdots\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 2^2+2^3+2^4+\cdots\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 2^3+2^4+\cdots\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 2^4+\cdots\\
$$